# divide and conquer: computing the time elapsed

Tags: java, recursion, brute-force, divide-and-conquer, floor

I have to do a little assignment at my university:

I have a server that runs 'n' independent services. All these services started at the same time in the past. And every service 'i' writes 'b[i]' lines to a log file on the server after a certain period of time 's[i]' in seconds. The input consist of 'l' the number of lines of the log file and 'n' the number of services. Then we have in the next 'n' lines for every service i: 's[i]' the period as mentioned and 'b[i]' the number of lines the services writes to the log file.

I have to compute from the number of lines in the log file, how long ago, in seconds, the programs all started running. Example:

```
input:  
19 3 
7 1
8 1
10 2

Output: 
42
```

I have to use divide and conquer, but I can't even figure out how to split this in subproblems. Also I have to use this function, where ss is the array of the periods of the services and bs the number of lines which each services writes to the log file:

```
long linesAt(int t, int[] ss, int[] bs) {
  long out = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < ss.length; i++) {
     // floor operation
     out += bs[i] * (long)(t/ss[i]);
  }
  return out;
```

ss and bs are basically arrays of the input, if we take the example they will look like this, where the row above is the index of the array:

ss:

```
0 1 2
7 8 10
```

bs:

```
0 1 2
1 1 2
```

It is easily seen that 42 should be the output

```
 linesAt(42) = floor(42/7)*1+floor(42/8)*1+floor(42/10)*2 = 19
```

Now I have to write a function

```
int solve(long l, int[] ss, int[] bs)
```

I already wrote some pseudocode in brute force, but I can't figure out how to solve this with the divide and conquer paradigm, my pseudocode looks like this:

```
Solve(l, ss, bs)
  out = 0
  t = 0
  while (out != l)
    out = linesAt(t, ss, bs)
    t++
  end while
  return t
```

I think I have to split l in some way, so to calculate the time for smaller lengths. But I don't really see how, because when you look at this it doesn't seem to be possible:

```
t           out
0..6        0
7           1
8           2
9           2
10          4
11..13      4
14          5
15          5
16          6
17..19      6
20          8
...
40          18
42          19
```

Chantal.

Comment: Chantal, did you translate the text of the problem from another language.

Comment: No I didn't, why? Is my english so bad?

Comment: No, it's just that your name sounds French. I did not completely understand the problem.

Comment: @Chantal I think you mean that each service writes a different number of lines after a different period. To label these values as 'b' and 's' is confusing as it implies they are the same for each service. Typically one would write "'b[i]' (where i is the service)", or use another such notation which indicates that there are multiple values.

Comment: @Tarik do you understand now?

Comment: @davmac I wish I could do a little i at s and b, like in latex s_i and b_i, but that doesn't work. So I had chosen for this way, I did however say that it is for every service 'n' lines, so I thought it was clear. But I will change it in s[i] and b[i], although that seems a little weird, because to me it looks like you then already have an array with the input, which is definitely not the case in the beginning. But your suggestion is I think better and more clear. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: I am trying to understand the input. The log file contains 19 lines in total. There are 3 processes. Process 1 wrote 1 line at time s=7 seconds. Process 2 wrote 1 line at s=8 and process 3 wrote 3 lines at s=10. Is that correct?

Comment: Shall we assume that log lines are written by processes at regular intervals?

Comment: Do you have the original problem statement? Did you rephrase it somehow?

Comment: @Tarik That is almost correct, service 3 wrote 2 lines at t=10. So total number of lines at t=10 is 1 + 1 + 2 = 4. You other questions: Yes the lines are written at regular intervals, for service s[0] for example at t = {7, 14, 21, 28, 35, 42}. I don't think I rephrased it somehow, and I don't think it is appropriated to post the exercise of my university on internet, but I can send you a pdf, can you pm somehow? Then I will send you a copy. Also I think you misunderstood 's' and 't'. s is the period of time the service writes 'b' lines. So 's' is constant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to solve an integer equation:

```
 floor(n/7)*1+floor(n/8)*1+floor(n/10)*2 = 19
```

You can remove the floor function and solve for n and get a lower bound and upper bound, then search between these two bounds.

Solving the following equation:

```
(n/7)*1+(n/8)*1+(n/10)*2 = 19
n=19/(1/7+1/8+2/10)
```

Having found n, which range of value m0 will be such that `floor (m0 / 7) = floor (n/7)`?

```
floor (n/7) * 7 <= m0 <= (ceiling (n/7) * 7) - 1
```

In the same manner, calculate m1 and m2.

Take max (mi) as upperbound and min(mi) as lowerbound for i between 1 and 3 .

A binary search at this point will probably be an overkill.

Comment: Good idea. In this case t=40,61,  so the lower bound would be t=41, which is actually already a good approximation. So for the binary search I will use as my min 41. Then I will have my maximum be 2*min=82, then I will use binary search between these values, this could actually work! I will give this a shot! Thx and I will keep you updated.

Comment: It looks like the whole idea of the exercise was to have you use binary search. The lower bound, upper bound thing is but a bonus. I think you could come up with a smaller lower bound (with some math analysis). I will have a look at it...

Comment: Oke, basically I got it working, your suggestion for the bounds worked very well. But I have know a special case, where the input is:                                    1 2
2147483647 2147483647
2147483645 1. The output is easy: 2147483645. But now my min will be 1, because 2147483647/2147483647 + 1/2147483645 = 1, so the program never finds the solution. I thought of making a priority queue and then remove the min and then compare this with estimated minimum, if this minimum is higher than the estimated, I could use that mininum instead of the estimated, but then it will..

Comment: .. almost always have the minimum of the queue instead of the estimated which makes the program slower, also the maximum will then not be 2*min. Any suggestions how this could be done easier?

Comment: The upperbound is overestimated. In a previous comment, I meant you could come up with a smaller upperbound.

Comment: I think you are right, the maximum is overestimated. But I am now trying to solve the minimum, because the minimum calculation is in most cases a good estimation for the minimum. However in the test case I mentioned where l=1 and n=2 and ss[] = {2147483647, 2147483645} and bs[] = {2147483647, 1}, the program fails, because it tries to find to the solution between t=1 and t=2, because min = l/sum, where sum is the sum of all the lines per second. So I am currently working on that, will look at a better upper bound though if I got this fixed, to get it more efficient.

Comment: Sorry didn't see your edited solution, think you are right, although you don't have to calculate m0, m1, .. , mn. Because you can just take the min of ss[] (in example 7 and special test case: 2147483645) and take the bounds for that I think. Will try this out thanks.

Comment: Oke, I tried your bounds and it got me passed all the public test cases, however I got stuck on one test case, which is hidden. I am already pretty sure what is going wrong. If you remember the input:  l=1 and n=2 and ss[] = {2147483647, 2147483645} and bs[] = {2147483647, 1} and output=2147483645. The program does solve this, but it will search between 0 <= t <= 2147483647, which is not very nice. Now imagine the input be very large (the max input size is n=10^6). Then if it finds min(mi)=0 and max(mi) = 2147483647, the program will be really inefficient, because the bounds are so wide.

Comment: So is there a better way for the bounds, or did we go in the wrong way with binary search?

Comment: I think the whole point of the exercise is to have you use binary search in lieu of brute force. As far as searching up to 2147483647, it will just take log2(2147483647)=31 trials, which is indeed very efficient. Now, as far as the bounds are concerned, to be frank with you, I did my best on limited time, and am not 100% sure it is correct. I am not worried about having the range too large. As you can see, binary search takes care of that. I am worried the solution does not lie between the bounds.

Comment: Back to the bounds, they should not be that much away from the solution you get by solving the equation without the floor function. If not, then there's definitely something wrong.

Comment: My suggestion is to forget about this bound thing to stay in the spirit of the exercise and start with n=1 and double it while floor(n/7)*1+floor( n  /8)*1+floor( n /10)*2 <= 19. Once it's greater than than 19 you now have a range whete you are sure the solution lies in. Binary search that range.

Comment: I fixed it, my computation for the smallest t wasn't fast enough somehow, I used the range 0 < t < 2^31 for the range, because simulations of runtime showed that the bounds don't really matter. I was wondering what would be the fastest way in theory. linesAt has O(n), finding lower bound has O(n) and highest bound has O(n) also. So without bounds: Binary search has O(log n), and every step in binary search we execute linesAt, so the algorithm has O(n log n), am I correct? And with bounds it will be: n + n + n log n, but less times n*log n, because we need less steps in the binary search, but..

Comment: overal time complexity will also be O(n log n), so in theory there is also not really a difference, am I correct? Thanks for all your help these days, you’ve been really helpful!

Comment: Or it might be log n^2, because in the binary search we execute linesAt n times, so we get log n*n, which is also O(log n). I am little bit confused...

Comment: Searching is log n. Multiply by m processes.

Comment: You mean n log n? Please explain. Every step in binary search the function is linesAt is called, in the worst case binary search has log2(2^31)=31 steps. So the loop is called 31 times in the worst case and the loop has O(n) of course. If I look at it in this way it's linear lol, but that seems really weird, however binary search is between constants, they are between 0 < t < 2^31, the range where binary search searches has nothing to do with the input size. It's a constant, so I think the algorithm might be of order O(31n) = O(n)

Comment: Well n log(m) ends up being O(n log (n). That said, if you assume having a constant range, then you end up with a constant search time bounded at 31 which IMHO makes it O(1). I did not like the idea of picking up 2^31 as an upperbound. I would have preferred any scheme where we do not hardcode the upperbound so as to stay in the spirit of the exercise and avoid confusion. Note that selecting 31 bit numbers is somewhat arbitrary since long is available and you even have BigInt types that are virtually as large as you want them to be.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a classic binary search would fit the bill, with a prior step to obtain a suitable maximum. You start with some estimate of time 't' (say 100) and call `linesAt` to obtain the lines for that `t`. If the value returned is too small (i.e. smaller than `l`), you double 't' and try again, until the number of lines is too *large*.

At this point, your `maximum` is `t` and your `minimum` is `t/2`. You then repeatedly:

- pick `t` as the point halfway between `maximum` and `minimum`
- call `linesAt(t,...)` to obtain the number of lines
- if you've found the target, stop.
- if you have too many lines, adjust the maximum: `maximum = t`
- if you have too few lines adjust the minimum: `minimum = t`

The above algorithm is a binary search - it splits the search space in half each iteration. Thus, it is an example of *divide-and-conquer*.

Comment: I already considered this too. This solution works, as does the brute force solution, although this is definitely better than the brute force, I am not sure whether this is the best and right solution. Because the input can become really large and basically you have to first make a guess and then start searching, it depends on how good your guess is, how long it will take for the program to find its solution. One of my test cases has l = 6543219876 and n = 1000000. Just saying t=100 is not going to work for this case (I think), because the program needs to terminate in at least 5s.

Comment: Making somehow a good guess would be key then with this algorithm.

Comment: Well, you could easily calculate the average lines per second - it would be the sum of the average lines per second for each service. This would probably allow you to make a very close guess.